# Transition isn't applied if invoked with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm struggling with a problem of not applying valid transition on dynamically created element. This is simple example demonstrating the problem:

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.style = 'width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green; opacity: 0; transition: opacity 1s linear;';
document.body.append(div);
div.style.opacity = 1;
```

The box shows binary. If I change to element inspector and change the opacity value 1 <=> 0, the transition already applies. Do I have to use stylesheets or is it different issue? If I don't intend to create special stylesheet just for this transition, then how do I properly notify the browser the property has changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the opacity at pageload, so it never technically *changes* and there is nothing to transition per se. You need to apply the change on the next event loop, which you can do with `setTimeout(..., 0)` (or use `requestAnimationFrame`):

```js
let green = document.createElement('div'),
    red = document.createElement('div');

green.style = 'width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green; opacity: 0; transition: opacity 1s linear;',
red.style = 'width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red; opacity: 0; transition: opacity 1s linear;';

document.body.appendChild(green),
document.body.appendChild(red);

// the box's opacity is set to 0 when this script runs,
// but when the callback below is executed, it will be
// set to 1, triggering the actual transition
setTimeout(() => red.style.opacity = 1, 0);

// requestAnimationFrame will do effectively the same
// thing, but will try to wait until a frame is rendered.
// setTimeout(..., 0) will execute on the next event loop
// regardless of frame rate
requestAnimationFrame(() => green.style.opacity = 1, 0);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Compare with:

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.style = 'width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green; opacity: 0; transition: opacity 1s linear;';
document.body.appendChild(div);

// no transition happens; the page loads, it sets the box's opacity to 1,
// and that's it - there's nothing to transition, as far as the browser
// can tell it has done its job and the element is all good
div.style.opacity = 1;
```

You can read more about repaint, reflow, and rendering performance here:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering

Comment: Thanks, though requestAnimationFrame worked only on first run, setTimeout(..., 0) seems to do the job. I was running the snippet not on pageload, but on demand, ie. when page was fully established, but I guess it's the same issue.